# current month not selected when go previous month and open the v-date-picker again

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify date picker and it's inside a dialog box. When I open the dialog box for first time it's showing current month and if I go to previous month and close the dialog box, then reopen it, it still remain in the previous month. I need to avoid it. Each time when the calendar opens, it should be in the current month without user to navigate to current month manually.

```html
<v-dialog v-model="isShow">
  <v-date-picker
    v-model="dates1"
    :max="max"
    :min="min"
    readonly
    range
    color="primary"
  ></v-date-picker>                                              
</v-dialog>
```

My date picker is as in above and is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-pine-lh7gm) recreating your issue? I've linked a hello world vue template.

 It's unlikely many here will be able to recreate this otherwise unless it's a common hickup in vuetify.

Comment: The date picker remains in the month to preserve what the user did, saving it in `v-model` at some point. I think it would be very annoying to scroll back to the year/month I wanted if I accidentally closed the datepicker. If I intentionally close the datepicker I am probably happy my changes were preserved instead of thrown away. You could deactivate navigating the months if that is a problem for you.

Comment: Is there any way to trigger the navigate month button action when I open the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind [`<v-date-picker>.pickerDate`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#picker-date) to a local data property that is reset to the current date when the dialog is closed.

1. Create a data property named `"pickerDate"`, and bind it to `<v-date-picker>.pickerDate` with the `.sync` modifier:

   ```html
   <template>
     <v-date-picker :pickerDate.sync="pickerDate" />
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         pickerDate: null,
       }
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Add a watcher on `isShow` to reset `pickerDate` when `isShow` is `false` (upon the dialog closing):

   ```html
   <script>
   export default {
     watch: {
       isShow(isShow) {
         if (!isShow) {
           const today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
           this.pickerDate = today
         }
       }
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuetify-reset-date-picker?file=components%2FDatePickerDialog.vue)